# HHVM standalone and runtime options

Tags: php, webserver, hhvm

I have been trying to run HHVM as standalone web server for multiple domains and it looks like they are switching to FCGI mode only https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options

Is that the case or running it as standalone is still possible on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use FastCGI mode and let nginx/Apache/whatever deal with being the webserver. HHVM's old built-in webserver has been deprecated for quite a number of releases now -- I can't find the old the wiki page on its deprecation, but it's been about six months or so. This more closely mirrors how PHP is often used, and removes a whole host of complicated HHVM-specific configuration mess. Many people are already familiar with how to make nginx/Apache serve files the way they want, and so we can just keep the HHVM-specific stuff in HHVM and let the full-featured webservers do what they are good at.

[The getting started guide](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Getting-Started) has a very quick, basic intro to getting FastCGI set up if you're using our prebuilt debian/ubuntu packages, and [the FastCGI wiki page](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI) contains all the details to get set up in some other environment.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Libevent-Removal is the wiki page about the removal of the libevent-based server.